# Create a automatic Version Tag in a Gitlab CICD Pipline

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

I have a problem with which I do not come further. I would like to automatically assign a tag with a version number in a Gitlab Pipline on a push to Master. Now the problem is that gitlab does not make a normal git clone or git checkout but checks out the explicit commit.
My current version number is in a file called version which is incremented by one by bash script.

my Bash Script:

```
# !/bin/bash

current_version=$(cat version)
step=0.01

echo $current_version
sum=$(echo "$current_version + $step"|bc)

echo $sum
printf $sum > version

 git add version
 git commit -a -m "add new Version"
# git tag -a v$sum -m 'Version $sum'
# git push origin --tags
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

but when i try to push the new version to git i get an error because it is not in a branch. i suspect that my approach is fundamentally wrong, but i can't find a better one. Do you have an idea how I can implement this cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

> i try to push the new version to git i get an error because it is not in a branch

Either set `GIT_STRATEGY` variable to `clone`, or first checkout a branch.

```
git checkout $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```